# iOS app syntax highlighting issues

Tags: bug, ios-app, syntax-highlighting

I have noticed that the iOS app isn't highlighting syntax correctly, even with the explicit comment:

```
<!-- language: whatever -->
```

For example, compare [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34833078/3001761) in Chrome for iOS (47.0.2526.107):

[image: correct formatting in browser]

with the SO app (1.4.2.3):

[image: incorrect formatting in app]

Comment: As far as I know, both the Android and iOS mobile apps always uses the default Prettify highlighting setting, i.e. `lang-default`.